# I need help with filter products in custom teplate

Tags: wp-query

I need some help with code below. I created a custom template and I am trying to get all the products, variations and their stock in a table and then try to filter them in products categories and in product attributes but I always get the all the products when I apply all the filters. Also I have I have a pagination. Thank you in advance.

```
<?php /* Template Name: Custom Products Table */ ?>
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">
<?php
// Retrieve product categories
$category_args = array(
    'taxonomy'   => 'product_cat',
    'hide_empty' => true,
);
$categories = get_terms($category_args);

// Define category and specific attribute filters
$category_filter = isset($_GET['product_cat']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']) : '';
$specific_attributes = array('pa_size', 'pa_color', 'pa_brand');

$attribute_filters = array();
foreach ($specific_attributes as $attribute_slug) {
    $attribute_value = isset($_GET[$attribute_slug]) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET[$attribute_slug]) : '';
    if (!empty($attribute_value)) {
        $attribute_filters[] = array(
            'taxonomy' => $attribute_slug,
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => $attribute_value,
        );
    }
}

// Prepare query arguments based on filters
$args = array(
    'post_type'      => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 10, // Adjust the number of products per page
    'paged'          => get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
    'tax_query'      => array(
        'relation' => 'AND', // Ensure both category and attribute filters are applied
    ),
);

// Category filter
if (!empty($category_filter)) {
    $args['tax_query'][] = array(
        'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
        'field'    => 'slug',
        'terms'    => $category_filter,
    );
}

// Attribute filters for specific attributes
if (!empty($attribute_filters)) {
    $args['tax_query'] = array_merge($args['tax_query'], $attribute_filters);
}

// Run the query
$products_query = new WP_Query($args);
?>

<!-- Filter Form: Category and Attribute Dropdowns -->
<form action="<?php echo esc_url(get_permalink()); ?>" method="get">
    <label for="category-filter">Filter by Category:</label>
    <select name="product_cat" id="category-filter">
        <option value="">All Categories</option>
        <?php foreach ($categories as $category) : ?>
            <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($category->slug); ?>" <?php selected($category_filter, $category->slug); ?>>
                <?php echo esc_html($category->name); ?>
            </option>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>


    <?php if (!empty($attributes)) : ?>
        <?php foreach ($attributes as $attribute_slug => $attribute_label) : ?>
            <?php
            // Get attribute terms for the dropdown
            $attribute_terms = get_terms(array('taxonomy' => 'pa_' . $attribute_slug, 'hide_empty' => true));
            ?>
            <label for="<?php echo esc_attr($attribute_slug); ?>-filter"><?php echo esc_html($attribute_label); ?>:</label>
            <select name="pa_<?php echo esc_attr($attribute_slug); ?>" id="<?php echo esc_attr($attribute_slug); ?>-filter">
                <option value="">All <?php echo esc_html($attribute_label); ?></option>
                <?php foreach ($attribute_terms as $term) : ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo esc_attr($term->slug); ?>" <?php selected(isset($_GET['pa_' . $attribute_slug]) && $_GET['pa_' . $attribute_slug] === $term->slug); ?>>
                        <?php echo esc_html($term->name); ?>
                    </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <input type="submit" value="Filter">
</form>

        
        

        <!-- Products Table -->
        <table class="products-table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Variation</th>
                    <th>Stock</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <?php
                $category_filter = isset($_GET['product_cat']) ? sanitize_text_field($_GET['product_cat']) : '';
                
                // Define the current page number
                $paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
                
                // Query products with or without category filter
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'product',
                    'posts_per_page' => 10, // Change this number to limit the products per page
                    'paged'         => $paged, // Add pagination support
                    'post_status' => 'publish',
                );

                if (!empty($category_filter)) {
                    $args['tax_query'] = array(
                        array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                            'field' => 'slug',
                            'terms' => $category_filter,
                        ),
                    );
                }

                $products = new WP_Query($args);

                if ($products->have_posts()) :
                    while ($products->have_posts()) :
                        $products->the_post();
                        global $product;

                        if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
                            $variations = $product->get_available_variations();

                            if ($variations) {
                                foreach ($variations as $variation) {
                                    $variation_id = $variation['variation_id'];
                                    $variation_obj = wc_get_product($variation_id);
                                    $variation_attrs = $variation_obj->get_variation_attributes();
                                    $variation_stock = $variation_obj->get_stock_quantity();
                ?>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo implode(', ', $variation_attrs); ?></td>
                                        <td><?php echo ($variation_stock > 0 ? $variation_stock : 'Out of Stock'); ?></td>
                                    </tr>
                <?php
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            $stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();
                ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php the_title(); ?></td>
                                <td>N/A</td>
                                <td><?php echo ($stock > 0 ? $stock : 'Out of Stock'); ?></td>
                            </tr>
                <?php
                        }
                    endwhile;
                // Add pagination links
                    echo '<div class="pagination">';
                    echo paginate_links(array(
                        'total'   => $products->max_num_pages,
                        'current' => max(1, $paged),
                    ));
                    echo '</div>';
                
                    wp_reset_postdata();
                else :
                    echo '<tr><td colspan="3">No products found</td></tr>';
                endif;
                ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```